# jquery fire event after multiple select rows

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a select element with multiple="true". On selecting value(s), I am doing a jquery ajax to get some values and display on website. It works mostly but a few times when I select more than one value, I get data twice. The ajax call runs twice. Any event which I can call after I select my value(s) from the select?

Currently I am using change event. There is not much that can be done. Any suggestions?

Comment: share the change event code and how ajax call is made.

Comment: If the `event` is running twice, normally is because it's `binded` twice. Please share your code and give examples of what you tried so far.

Comment: Sorry. I got the issue. I am using clone and passing true. Hence the event is running twice. Thank you.